# Passing data from one uiview to another

Tags: cocoa, uiview, xcode4.2

I have a form that I want the user to fill out.  Once they complete the form they will click save or submit.  I have all the coding for this.  What I need next is the data from the completed form to be passed into another view.

Need help

Comment: I'll guess that you actually want it passed to a different view **controller** so that it can be displayed in that controller's view...?  Are you using xib files or a storyboard, and what code/mechanism do you have for getting the next view onto the screen?

Comment: I am using xib.  I am using a button which saves the data entered but it is only displaying one line when I go to transfer the data from one UIView to the other

Comment: I suggest updating your question with the code you use for passing the data plus the code for collecting the other data that you want to pass.

Comment: Did you mean another View or Class? If you want to use value to another View( both View are in same class) you can use directly accessing via variable.

Answer (score -1):

Just overload the inithWith.... function for passing  your required details as a single variable, NSArray or NSDictionary

Comment: not need for that it is used for passing values to another method.